# How to take borders off table in R markdown

Tags: r, dplyr, format

Below is my code that I am using to manually create a table. When I knit in R markdown, there is a border about it and ## in front of each row. Is there a way to remove these items? Or would I be best creating data frames using these data points and then using gt?

```
 library(dplyr)
 comparison <- matrix(c(-2267,-345916,-185344,-44.4,-24.0,-57.1,"+1224","+191534","+80,347","51.4","55.4","43.4"),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
 colnames(comparison) <- c("Daycare Services","Total, All Industries","Accommodation and Food Services")
 rownames(comparison) <- c("Decline","% Decline","Recovery","% Recovery")
```

comparison <- as.table(comparison)

```
 comparison
```

Here is how I create it. Create a new R markdown file. Next, I put the code chunk in the first chunk (look below) and then enter the word, "comparison" in the place of summary(cars) below in the section that appears as such

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

comparison <- matrix(c(-2267,-345916,-185344,-44.4,-24.0,-57.1,"+1224","+191534","+80,347","51.4","55.4","43.4"),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(comparison) <- c("Daycare Services","Total, All Industries","Accommodation and Food Services")
rownames(comparison) <- c("Decline","% Decline","Recovery","% Recovery")
comparison <- as.table(comparison)

comparison
```

```
summary(cars)
```

Comment: @akrun edited the question. Hopefully it is clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are using `gt`, then we do

````
```{r}
library(gt)
library(dplyr)
comparison <- matrix(c(-2267,-345916,-185344,-44.4,-24.0,-57.1,"+1224","+191534","+80,347","51.4","55.4","43.4"),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
 colnames(comparison) <- c("Daycare Services","Total, All Industries","Accommodation and Food Services")
rownames(comparison) <- c("Decline","% Decline","Recovery","% Recovery")
out <- as.data.frame(comparison) 

 gt(out, rownames_to_stub = TRUE)
 ```
````

-output

[image]